# Multiple pipes in subprocess

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess, named-pipes

I am trying to use Sailfish, which takes multiple fastq files as arguments, in a ruffus pipeline. I execute Sailfish using the subprocess module in python, but `<()` in the subprocess call does not work even when I set `shell=True`.

This is the command I want to execute using python:

```
sailfish quant [options] -1 <(cat sample1a.fastq sample1b.fastq) -2 <(cat sample2a.fastq sample2b.fastq) -o [output_file]
```

or (preferably):

```
sailfish quant [options] -1 <(gunzip sample1a.fastq.gz sample1b.fastq.gz) -2 <(gunzip sample2a.fastq.gz sample2b.fastq.gz) -o [output_file]
```

A generalization:

```
someprogram <(someprocess) <(someprocess)
```

How would I go about doing this in python? Is subprocess the right approach?

Comment: related: [Bash style process substitution with Python's Popen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15343447/4279)

Comment: related to the title: [How do I use subprocess.Popen to connect multiple processes by pipes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To emulate the [bash process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_call

check_call('someprogram <(someprocess) <(anotherprocess)',
           shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

In Python, you could use named pipes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen

with named_pipes(n=2) as paths:
    someprogram = Popen(['someprogram'] + paths)
    processes = []
    for path, command in zip(paths, ['someprocess', 'anotherprocess']):
        with open(path, 'wb', 0) as pipe:
            processes.append(Popen(command, stdout=pipe, close_fds=True))
    for p in [someprogram] + processes:
        p.wait()
```

where `named_pipes(n)` is:

```
import os
import shutil
import tempfile
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def named_pipes(n=1):
    dirname = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    try:
        paths = [os.path.join(dirname, 'named_pipe' + str(i)) for i in range(n)]
        for path in paths:
            os.mkfifo(path)
        yield paths
    finally:
        shutil.rmtree(dirname)
```

---

Another and more preferable way (no need to create a named entry on disk) to implement the bash process substitution is to use `/dev/fd/N` filenames (if they are available) as [suggested by @Dunes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28844027/4279). On FreeBSD, [*`fdescfs(5)`* (`/dev/fd/#`) creates entries for all file descriptors opened by the process](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fdescfs&sektion=5). To test availability, run:

```
$ test -r /dev/fd/3 3</dev/null && echo /dev/fd is available
```

If it fails; try to symlink `/dev/fd`  to [`proc(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) as it is done on some Linuxes:

```
$ ln -s /proc/self/fd /dev/fd
```

Here's `/dev/fd`-based implementation of `someprogram <(someprocess) <(anotherprocess)` bash command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from contextlib import ExitStack
from subprocess import CalledProcessError, Popen, PIPE

def kill(process):
    if process.poll() is None: # still running
        process.kill()

with ExitStack() as stack: # for proper cleanup
    processes = []
    for command in [['someprocess'], ['anotherprocess']]:  # start child processes
        processes.append(stack.enter_context(Popen(command, stdout=PIPE)))
        stack.callback(kill, processes[-1]) # kill on someprogram exit

    fds = [p.stdout.fileno() for p in processes]
    someprogram = stack.enter_context(
        Popen(['someprogram'] + ['/dev/fd/%d' % fd for fd in fds], pass_fds=fds))
    for p in processes: # close pipes in the parent
        p.stdout.close()
# exit stack: wait for processes
if someprogram.returncode != 0: # errors shouldn't go unnoticed
   raise CalledProcessError(someprogram.returncode, someprogram.args)
```

Note: on my Ubuntu machine, the `subprocess` code works only in Python 3.4+, despite `pass_fds` being available since Python 3.2.

Comment: Thanks J.F. Sebastian! It actually worked with the simple subprocess argument `executable='/bin/bash'` that I was missing before. It works now with this call: `check_call('sailfish quant [options] <(gunzip -c file1 file2) <(gunzip -c file3 file4)', shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')`. Thank you so much for your help! You really went above and beyond in your answer--you not only helped me solve my problem but also helped me better understand piping in python.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst J.F. Sebastian has provided an answer using named pipes it is possible to do this with anonymous pipes.

```
import shlex
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

inputcmd0 = "zcat hello.gz" # gzipped file containing "hello"
inputcmd1 = "zcat world.gz" # gzipped file containing "world"

def get_filename(file_):
    return "/dev/fd/{}".format(file_.fileno())

def get_stdout_fds(*processes):
    return tuple(p.stdout.fileno() for p in processes)

# setup producer processes
inputproc0 = Popen(shlex.split(inputcmd0), stdout=PIPE)
inputproc1 = Popen(shlex.split(inputcmd1), stdout=PIPE)

# setup consumer process
# pass input processes pipes by "filename" eg. /dev/fd/5
cmd = "cat {file0} {file1}".format(file0=get_filename(inputproc0.stdout), 
    file1=get_filename(inputproc1.stdout))
print("command is:", cmd)
# pass_fds argument tells Popen to let the child process inherit the pipe's fds
someprogram = Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=PIPE, 
    pass_fds=get_stdout_fds(inputproc0, inputproc1))

output, error = someprogram.communicate()

for p in [inputproc0, inputproc1, someprogram]:
    p.wait()

assert output == b"hello\nworld\n"
```

Comment: your code does: `inputcmd | someproc` -- it is different from `someproc <(inputcmd)`.  btw, you should call `inputproc.communicate()` instead of `inputproc.wait()`, to close `inputproc.stdout.close()` in the parent so that `inputproc` wouldn't hang if `someproc` exits prematurely. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve with `StreamConnector` but it seems bloated.

Comment: My mistake. I thought `<(cmdlist)` connected a series of commands stdout to the stdin of the consumer process. The class was meant to cat-like utility for streams rather than files. Answer is much more simple now.

Comment: `/dev/fd/#` or named pipes if the former is unavailable is exactly how bash implements the process substitution. You should close pipes in the parent so that if `inputproc1` or `inputproc2` die prematurely; `someprogram` could exit sooner. Otherwise *the solution should work on Python 3.4+*.  I've added an exception-safe version of the code to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28840955/4279) (just as an exercise).

Comment: about pipes I meant the other way around: if `someprogram` dies prematurely then the parent Python script will hang on `p.wait()` after `inputproc[01]` fill their OS stdout pipe buffers (~65K on my machine) if you don't close the pipes (`inputproc[01].stdout`) in the parent.