# Invoking perl script with variable input and file output as arguments from python

Tags: python, perl, subprocess, stringio, shlex

I have a perl script that can be executed from the console as follows:

```
perl perlscript.pl -i input.txt -o output.txt --append
```

I want to execute this script from my python code. I figured out that `subprocess.Popen` can be used to connect to perl and I can pass my arguments with it. But, I also want to pass a variable (made by splitting up a text file) in place of input.txt. 
I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work and gives an obvious TypeError in line 8:

```
import re, shlex, subprocess, StringIO
f=open('fulltext.txt','rb')
text= f.read()
l = re.split('\n\n',str(text))
intxt = StringIO.StringIO()
for i in range(len(l)):
    intxt.write(l[i])
    command_line='perl cnv_ltrfinder2gff.pl -i '+intxt+' -o output.gff --append'
    args=shlex.split(command_line)
    p = subprocess.Popen(args)
```

Is there any other work around for this?

EDIT: Here is a sample of the file fulltext.txt. Entries are separated by a line.

```
Predict protein Domains 0.021 second
>Sequence: seq1 Len:13143 [1] seq1 Len:13143 Location : 9 - 13124 Len: 13116 Strand:+ Score    : 6 [LTR region similarity:0.959] Status   : 11110110000 5'-LTR   : 9 - 501 Len: 493 3'-LTR   : 12633 - 13124 Len: 492 5'-TG    : TG , TG 3'-CA    : CA , CA TSR      : NOT FOUND Sharpness: 1,1 Strand + : PBS   : [14/20] 524 - 543 (LysTTT) PPT   : [12/15] 12553 - 12567

Predict protein Domains 0.019 second
>Sequence: seq5 Len:11539 [1] seq5 Len:11539 Location : 7 - 11535 Len: 11529 Strand:+ Score    : 6 [LTR region similarity:0.984] Status   : 11110110000 5'-LTR   : 7 - 506 Len: 500 3'-LTR   : 11036 - 11535 Len: 500 5'-TG    : TG , TG 3'-CA    : CA , CA TSR      : NOT FOUND Sharpness: 1,1 Strand + : PBS   : [15/22] 515 - 536 (LysTTT) PPT   : [11/15] 11020 - 11034
```

I want to separate them and pass each entry block to the perl script. All the files are in the same directory.

Comment: Can the Perl script read the input from stdin instead of a file?

Comment: No it can't. The script I am using is: [link](https://github.com/jestill/dawgpaws/blob/fb0a40506be1ed8afce0049b6cfe3e4b52cd58dc/scripts/cnv_ltrfinder2gff.pl)

Comment: @RimjhimRoyChoudhury: the code says it can accept input from stdin (it even reminds you about it: [*"Expecting input from STDIN"*](https://github.com/jestill/dawgpaws/blob/fb0a40506be1ed8afce0049b6cfe3e4b52cd58dc/scripts/cnv_ltrfinder2gff.pl#L294)). Try to omit `infile` option or pass an empty `''` filename or `'-'` or `/dev/stdin` in bash.

Comment: On Unix, you could [use named pipes or `/dev/fd/N` filenames](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28840955/4279) to avoid writing the input data on disk if a child process reads only from files.

Answer (score 1):

you might be interested in the [os module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system)
and [string formatting](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm)

**Edit**

I think I uderstand what you want now. correct me if I am wrong, but I think:

- You want to split your fulltext.txt into blocks.
- Every block contains a seq(number)
- You want to run your perl script once for every block with as input file your seq(number)

if this is what you want, you could use the following code.

```
import os

in_file = 'fulltext.txt'
seq = []

with open(in_file,'r') as handle:
    lines = handle.readlines()
    for i in range(0,len(lines)):
        if lines[i].startswith(">"):
            seq.append(lines[i].rstrip().split(" ")[1])

for x in seq:
    command = "perl perl cnv_ltrfinder2gff.pl -i %s.txt -o output.txt --append"%x
    os.system(command)
```

Comment: It gives me an error: `sh: 1: cannot open StringIO.StringIO: No such file`

Comment: are all files located in the same directory? what is in the fulltext.txt and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Yes, all the files are located in the same directory. I have provided a sample input for the script.

Comment: It gives me another error: ERROR: ERROR: `Can not open LTR_FINDER result file
 seq1.txt
ERROR: Can not open LTR_FINDER result file
 seq2.txt`

Answer (score 0):

[The docs for `--infile` option](https://github.com/jestill/dawgpaws/blob/fb0a40506be1ed8afce0049b6cfe3e4b52cd58dc/scripts/cnv_ltrfinder2gff.pl#L1007):

> Path of the input file. If an input file is not provided, the program
>   will expect input from STDIN.

You could omit `--infile` and pass input via a pipe (stdin) instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with open('fulltext.txt') as file: # read input data
    blocks = file.read().split('\n\n')

# run a separate perl process for each block
args = 'perl cnv_ltrfinder2gff.pl -o output.gff --append'.split()
for block in blocks:
    p = Popen(args, stdin=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    p.communicate(block)
    if p.returncode != 0:
        print('non-zero exit status: %s on block: %r' % (p.returncode, block))
```

You can run several `perl` scripts concurrently:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool # use threads

def run((i, block)):
    filename = 'out%03d.gff' % i
    args = ['perl', 'cnv_ltrfinder2gff.pl', '-o', filename]
    p = Popen(args, stdin=PIPE, universal_newlines=True, close_fds=True)
    p.communicate(block)
    return p.returncode, filename

exit_statuses, filenames = zip(*Pool().map(run, enumerate(blocks, start=1)))
```

It runs several (equal to the number of CPUs on your system) child processes in parallel. You could specify a different number of worker threads (pass to `Pool()`).