# Create and pipe a file-like object as input for a command

Tags: python, linux, file, subprocess

I'm looking for a better way to do this, if possible:

```
import subprocess

f = open('temp.file', 'w+')
f.write('hello world')
f.close()

out = subprocess.check_output(['cat', 'temp.file'])

print out

subprocess.check_output(['rm', 'temp.file'])
```

In this example I'm creating a file and passing it as input to `cat` (in reality it's not `cat` I'm running but some other program that parses an input `pcap` file).

What I'm wondering is, is there a way in Python I can create a 'file-like object' with some content, and pipe this file-like object as input to a command-line program. If it is possible, I reckon it would be more efficient than writing a file to the disk and then deleting that file.

Comment: Is this actually a bottleneck for your program or are you just assuming it might be at some point?

Comment: If the recipient program is not configured to read from STDIN, then you don't have a choice but to write to disk; otherwise you could stream the data in by simple redirection - assuming I understood what you are trying to do.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: there are [named pipes and /dev/fd/N filenames  (fdescfs)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28840955/4279) that allow you to pass the input as a filename without writing the corresponding content to disk.

Answer (score 4):

`check_output` takes a `stdin` input argument to specify a file-like object to connect to the process's standard input.

```
with open('temp.file') as input:
    out = subprocess.check_output(['cat'], stdin=input)
```

Also, there's no need to shell out to run `rm`; you can remove the file directly from Python:

```
os.remove('temp.file')
```

Comment: you can pass a file-like object only if `.fileno()` returns a valid file descriptor e.g., you can't pass `StringIO` object.

Answer (score 3):

If the program is configured to read from `stdin`, you can use [Popen.communicate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> p = Popen('cat', stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
>>> out, err = p.communicate(input=b"Hello world!")
>>> out
'Hello world!'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write to a TemporaryFile

```
import subprocess
from tempfile import TemporaryFile
f = TemporaryFile("w")
f.write("foo")
f.seek(0)
out = subprocess.check_output(['cat'],stdin=f)

print(out)
b'foo'
```

If you just want to write to a file like object and get the content:

```
from io import StringIO
f = StringIO()
f.write("foo")

print(f.getvalue())
```

Answer (score 3):

If the command accepts only filenames, if it doesn't read input from its stdin i.e., if you can't use [`stdin=PIPE` + `.communicate()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30891532/4279) or [`stdin=real_file`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30891561/4279) then you could try `/dev/fd/#` filenames:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import subprocess
import threading

def pump_input(pipe):
    with pipe:
        for i in range(3):
            print(i, file=pipe)

r, w = os.pipe()
try:
    threading.Thread(target=pump_input, args=[open(w, 'w')]).start()
    out = subprocess.check_output(['cat', '/dev/fd/'+str(r)], pass_fds=[r])
finally:
    os.close(r)
print('got:', out)
```

No content touches the disk. The input is passed to the subprocess via the pipe directly.

If you have a file-like object that is not a real file (otherwise, just pass its name as the command-line argument) then `pump_input()` could look like:

```
import shutil

def pump_input(pipe):
    with pipe:
        shutil.copyfileobj(file_like_object, pipe)
```

Comment: This is fantastic! I generalized this into a fancy context manager that accepts a string, and yields an object that can be passed directly to `pass_fds` as well as placed directly within `args`: https://gist.github.com/theY4Kman/2a80767e9fdabcc4634556c667fa59c8

Comment: Great! What about if the output is too large to fit in memory, so I want to stream it to another thread/process? (Or obtain a file-like object to call `.read()` on, which provides back-pressure by blocking writes when full.)

Comment: @falsePockets write as much data as you like in your `pump_input()`. `check_output` and `cat` are just examples. Use your own command instead of `cat`. If your command produces unlimited output, you can redirect it into another process (the simplest option is to run shell ["data-source | data-sink"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295459/4279)). If you want to consume data in Python, see [Read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279)