# Python: pass to subprocess a temporary generated file not as the last argument

Tags: python, subprocess, command-line-arguments, temporary-files

how to use subprocess if my temp-file argument is in the middle of the command? For example a terminal command looks like this:

```
program subprogram -a -b tmpFILE otherFILE
```

I tried variations of this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from tempfile import SpooledTemporaryFile as tempfile
tmpFILE=tempfile()
tmpFILE.write(someList)
tmpFILE.seek(0)
print Popen(['program','subprogram', '-a', '-b', otherFile],stdout=PIPE,stdin=tmpFILE).stdout.read()
f.close()
```

or

```
print Popen(['program','subprogram', '-a', '-b', tmpFILE, otherFile],stdout=PIPE,stdin=tmpFILE).stdout.read()
```

but nothing works... My temporary generated file in python shouldn't be as the last parameter.

Thanks

Comment: Try passing `tmpFILE.name`.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason to use `SpooledTemporaryFile` instead of other types of temp file? If not, I recommend using `NamedTemporaryFile` as you can retrieve the name from it. I have tried to retrieve the name from `SpooledTemporaryFile` and got `'<fdopen>'` which does not seem to be valid.

Here is the suggested code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import tempfile

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp_file:
    temp_file.write(someList)
    temp_file.flush()
    process = Popen(['program', 'subprogram', '-a', '-b', temp_file.name, otherFile], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

## Discussion

- Using the with statement, you don't have to worry about closing the file. As soon as the with block is finished, the file is automatically closed.
- Instead of calling `seek`, you should call `flush` to commit your file buffer to disk before calling `program`.

Comment: both `.seek(0)` and `.flush()` should pass the data to OS (so that `program` could read it back). As an alternative a [named pipe or  `/dev/fd/#` filenames could be used](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28840955/4279) (to avoid writing all at once or to avoid writing the data to disk).

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile), it is not guaranteed that you can open a `NamedTemporaryFile` again.