# Pass strings as subprocess' input via multiple named pipes in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, diff, named-pipes

I have spent a considerable time trying to get the Linux diff and patch tools to work in python with strings. To achieve this I try to use named pipes since they seem the most robust way to go. The problem is that this doesn't work for big files.

Example:

```
a, b = str1, str2 # ~1MB each string

fname1, fname2 = mkfifos(2)
proc = subprocess.Popen(['diff', fname1, fname2], \
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

print('Writing first file.')
with open(fname1, 'w') as f1:
    f1.write(a)
print('Writing second file.')
with open(fname2, 'w') as f2:
    f2.write(b)
```

This hangs at the first write. If figured out that if I use `a[:6500]` it hangs on the second write. So I would assume it has something to do with the buffer. I tried manually flushing after each write, closing, using the lowlevel `os.open(f, 'r', 0)` with 0 buffer but still the same issue.

I thought of looping through the write in chunks but that feels wrong in a high level language like Python. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't the fifo buffer fill up if you just write to one first - or would diff empty only on of them gradually?

Comment: @J.P.Petersen yes I assume that is what is happening; diff is reading both files gradually so it ends up in a deadlock. It works fine if the first write is done in a thread.

Comment: if the input strings `str1`, `str2` are from other processes; take a look at the question from [the subprocess tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/subprocess/info) that shows ["how to emulate the bash process substitution such as `a <(b) <(c)`"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28840575/4279)

Answer (score 0):

A named pipe is still a pipe. It has a finite buffer on Linux. You can't write an unlimited output unless someone reads from the other end of the pipe at the same time.

If `f1.write(a)` blocks then it means `diff` doesn't read all the input files at once (it seems logical: the purpose of the `diff` program is to compare files *line by line*--reading from the first file won't be too far ahead of the reading from the second file).

To write different data to different places concurrently, you could use threads/async.io:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Thread

def write_input_async(path, text):
    def writelines():
        with open(path, 'w') as file:
            for line in text.splitlines(keepends=True):
                file.write(line)
    Thread(target=writelines, daemon=True).start()

with named_pipes(2) as paths, \
    Popen(['diff'] + paths, stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True) as p:
    for path, text in zip(paths, [a, b]):
        write_input_async(path, text)
    output, errors = p.communicate()
```

where [`named_pipes(n)` context manager is defined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28840955/4279).

Note: unless you call `.communicate()`; the `diff` process may hang as soon as any of its stdout/stderr OS pipe buffers fill up.

---

You could [consider whether `difflib.context_diff(a, b)` would work in your case](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html).